# Applying MVC With JavaFx

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller, javafx

I'm new to the GUI world/OO design pattern and I want to use MVC pattern for my GUI application, I have read a little tutorial about MVC pattern, the Model will contain the data, the View will contain the visual element and the Controller will tie between the View and the Model.

I have a View that contains a ListView node, and the ListView will be filled with names, from a Person Class (Model). But I'm a little confused about one thing.

What I want to know is if loading the data from a file is the responsibility of the Controller or the Model?? And the ObservableList of the names: should it be stored in the Controller or the Model?

Comment: This PAQ was insightful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187932/mvc-with-javafx?rq=1

Comment: You might want to take a look at the MVVM pattern which is a variation of the MVC pattern that works very well with JavaFX imho.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

There are many different variations of this pattern. In particular, "MVC" in the context of a web application is interpreted somewhat differently to "MVC" in the context of a thick client (e.g. desktop) application (because a web application has to sit atop the request-response cycle). This is just one approach to implementing MVC in the context of a thick client application, using JavaFX.

Your `Person` class is not really the model, unless you have a very simple application: this is typically what we call a domain object, and the model will contain references to it, along with other data. In a narrow context, such as when you are *just* thinking about the `ListView`, you can think of the `Person` as your data model (it models the data in each element of the `ListView`), but in the wider context of the application, there is more data and state to consider.

If you are displaying a `ListView<Person>` the data you need, as a minimum, is an `ObservableList<Person>`. You might also want a property such as `currentPerson`, that might represent the selected item in the list.

If the *only* view you have is the `ListView`, then creating a separate class to store this would be overkill, but any real application will usually end up with multiple views. At this point, having the data shared in a model becomes a very useful way for different controllers to communicate with each other.

So, for example, you might have something like this:

```
public class DataModel {

    private final ObservableList<Person> personList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    
    private final ObjectProperty<Person> currentPerson = new SimpleObjectPropery<>(null);

    public ObjectProperty<Person> currentPersonProperty() {
        return currentPerson ;
    }

    public final Person getCurrentPerson() {
        return currentPerson().get();
    }

    public final void setCurrentPerson(Person person) {
        currentPerson().set(person);
    }

    public ObservableList<Person> getPersonList() {
        return personList ;
    }
}
```

Now you might have a controller for the `ListView` display that looks like this:

```
public class ListController {

    @FXML
    private ListView<Person> listView ;

    private DataModel model ;

    public void initModel(DataModel model) {
        // ensure model is only set once:
        if (this.model != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Model can only be initialized once");
        }

        this.model = model ;
        listView.setItems(model.getPersonList());

        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> 
            model.setCurrentPerson(newSelection));

        model.currentPersonProperty().addListener((obs, oldPerson, newPerson) -> {
            if (newPerson == null) {
                listView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            } else {
                listView.getSelectionModel().select(newPerson);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This controller essentially just binds the data displayed in the list to the data in the model, and ensures the model's `currentPerson` is always the selected item in the list view.

Now you might have another view, say an editor, with three text fields for the `firstName`, `lastName`, and `email` properties of a person. It's controller might look like:

```
public class EditorController {

    @FXML
    private TextField firstNameField ;
    @FXML
    private TextField lastNameField ;
    @FXML
    private TextField emailField ;

    private DataModel model ;

    public void initModel(DataModel model) {
        if (this.model != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Model can only be initialized once");
        }
        this.model = model ;
        model.currentPersonProperty().addListener((obs, oldPerson, newPerson) -> {
            if (oldPerson != null) {
                firstNameField.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldPerson.firstNameProperty());
                lastNameField.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldPerson.lastNameProperty());
                emailField.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldPerson.emailProperty());
            }
            if (newPerson == null) {
                firstNameField.setText("");
                lastNameField.setText("");
                emailField.setText("");
            } else {
                firstNameField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newPerson.firstNameProperty());
                lastNameField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newPerson.lastNameProperty());
                emailField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newPerson.emailProperty());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now if you set things up so both these controllers are sharing the same model, the editor will edit the currently selected item in the list.

Loading and saving data should be done via the model. Sometimes you will even factor this out into a separate class to which the model has a reference (allowing you to easily switch between a file-based data loader and a database data loader, or an implementation that accesses a web service, for example). In the simple case you might do

```
public class DataModel {

    // other code as before...

    public void loadData(File file) throws IOException {

        // load data from file and store in personList...

    }

    public void saveData(File file) throws IOException {
 
        // save contents of personList to file ...
    }
}
```

Then you might have a controller that provides access to this functionality:

```
public class MenuController {

    private DataModel model ;

    @FXML
    private MenuBar menuBar ;

    public void initModel(DataModel model) {
        if (this.model != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Model can only be initialized once");
        }
        this.model = model ;
    }

    @FXML
    public void load() {
        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(menuBar.getScene().getWindow());
        if (file != null) {
            try {
                model.loadData(file);
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                // handle exception...
            }
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void save() {

        // similar to load...

    }
}
```

Now you can easily assemble an application:

```
public class ContactApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        FXMLLoader listLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("list.fxml"));
        root.setCenter(listLoader.load());
        ListController listController = listLoader.getController();

        FXMLLoader editorLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("editor.fxml"));
        root.setRight(editorLoader.load());
        EditorController editorController = editorLoader.getController();

        FXMLLoader menuLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("menu.fxml"));
        root.setTop(menuLoader.load());
        MenuController menuController = menuLoader.getController();

        DataModel model = new DataModel();
        listController.initModel(model);
        editorController.initModel(model);
        menuController.initModel(model);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

As I said, there are many variations of this pattern (and this is probably more a model-view-presenter, or "passive view" variation), but that's one approach (one I basically favor). It's a bit more natural to provide the model to the controllers via their constructor, but then it's a lot harder to define the controller class with a `fx:controller` attribute. This pattern also lends itself strongly to dependency injection frameworks.

**Update:** full code for this example is [here](https://github.com/james-d/SimpleMVP).

If you are interested in a tutorial on MVC in JavaFX, see:

- The Eden Coding tutorial: [How to apply MVC in JavaFX](https://edencoding.com/mvc-in-javafx/)

Comment: Great summary of the design pattern but would your code not always throw an exception when you set the model because the if-statement refers to the (hopefully non-null) model parameter and not the model instance variable? You should use if (this.model != null) instead.

Comment: Oh, nice spot: thanks. That's what comes of typing code directly in here, instead of actually running it first. Updated with fix.

Comment: @James_D is there a reason that you do not bidirectionally bind listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty() to the model.currentPersonProperty() ? Afaik the selectedItemProperty is also null when nothing is selected.

Comment: @findusl [`SelectionModel.selectedItemProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedItemProperty) is a `ReadOnlyProperty` (so it doesn't have any `bind` methods, and can't be passed to a `bindBidirectional(...)` method).

Comment: Thank you very much for the example and also for the [version without FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36873768/2241463).

Comment: @James_D What a thorough answer, thank you very much!

Comment: @James_D What if I want to visualize objects from the model as nodes on the view? Currently I'm using the controller class of someAnchorPane.fxml, to store a list of <VertexView (extends Stackpane)> and I'm trying to synchronize that with the model using Changelisteners.. is that the correct way to use MVC?

Answer (score 4):

> What i want to know is that if loading the data from a file is the responsibility of the Controller Or the model?

For me the model is only responsible of bringing the required data structures that represent the business logic of the application.

The action of loading that data from any source should be done by the Controller Layer. You could also use the [repository pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305199/repository-pattern-how-to-understand-it-and-how-does-it-work-with-complex-en), which can help you in abstracting from the type of source when you are acessing the data from the view. With this implemented you should not care if the Repository implementation is loading the data from file, SQL, NoSQL, Web service ...

> And the ObservableList of the names will be stored in the controller or the model?

For me the `ObservableList` is part of the View. It is the kind of data structure you can bind to JavaFX controls. So for example a `ObservableList<String>` could be populated with Strings from the model but the `ObservableList` reference should be an attribute of some View´s class.
In JavaFX it's very pleasant to bind JavaFX controls with Observable Properties backed by domain objects from the model.

You could also have a look to [viewmodel concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421874/basic-concepts-of-mvvm-what-should-a-viewmodel-do). For me a JavaFX bean backed by a POJO could be considered as a view-model, you could see it as a model object ready to be presented in the view. So for example if your view needs to show some total value calculated from 2 model attributes, this total value could be an attribute of the view-model. This attribute would not be persisted and it would be calculated any time you show the view.