# Split a method into two separate ones and reuse the same list across the invocations

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a method as follows (simplified for clarity and brevity):

```
public static List<Person> getPersons(String a, int b, DataSetX dataSetX, DataSetY dataSetY) {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        
        if(dataSetX != null) {
            while (dataSetX.hasNext()) {
                // create an instance of person with very specific attributes set                
                persons.add(processX(dataSetX.next()));
            }
        }

        if(dataSetY != null) {
            while (dataSetY.hasNext()) {
               // create an instance of person with very specific attributes set               
                persons.add(processY(dataSetY.next()));
            }
        }
        return persons;        
    }
```

The method in reality is a bit more complicate than this (doing a bit more processing using also the `a` and `b` variables) but overall this is the method structure.

I was thinking to split this method into 2, one method for dealing with `DataSetX` and the other with `DataSetY`.
I was thinking to structure it as follows:

```
public static List<Person> getPersons(String a, DataSetX dataSetX, List<Person> persons) {
        if(dataSetX != null) {
            while (dataSetX.hasNext()) {
                // create an instance of person with very specific attributes set
                persons.add(processX(dataSetX.next()));
            }
        }
        return persons;
}
```

I would then call the methods as follows:

```
List<Person> persons = getPersons(a, dataSetX, new ArrayList<Person>());
getPersons(a, dataSetX, persons);    
// now I can use persons list with the result of both present
```

With this approach I reuse the same list and don't need to concat 2 different lists from 2 different methods if I just created the list inside the methods and returned.
On the other side it looks kind of weird and possibly error prone.

Is there a way to be able to split the function and avoid creating multiple lists and merging them (as I need 1 list in the end).
Is there some design pattern suited for this?

Comment: I think on the last code block is missing the dataSetY?

Comment: The first simple thing I would change, is change the name from getPersons to addPersons. Get seems that the method won't change the state in any parameter.

Comment: @digao_mb: I omitted it because it is basically similar but only goes over `dataSetY`. I can add it if it causes confusion

Answer (score 0):

In my view, this method is not simple and future user of this method will be surprised that this method adds
data to `List<Person> persons`. Why? As method is named `getPersons`. In my view, people will be think that this method will just return data, not add new data to `List<Person> persons`.

So, it is better to be consistent with naming of method and do just one thing in method. So I would just read data in method:

```
public static List<Person> getPersons(String a, DataSetX dataSetX) {
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    if(dataSetX != null) {
        while (dataSetX.hasNext()) {
            // create an instance of person with very specific attributes set
            persons.add(processX(dataSetX.next()));
        }
    }
    return persons;
}
```

and the second method should look like the above method:

```
public static List<Person> getPersons(String a, DataSetY dataSetX) {
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    if(dataSetX != null) {
        while (dataSetX.hasNext()) {
            // create an instance of person with very specific attributes set
            persons.add(processX(dataSetX.next()));
        }
    }
    return persons;
}
```

In addition, this method can be placed in repository layer. [Read more about Repository pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305199/repository-pattern-how-to-understand-it-and-how-does-it-work-with-complex-en).

And then you can create a collection and add these data from two methods. I am not Java guy, however, I think
it can be done like this:

```
List<Person> overallPersons = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(list, getPersons(String a, DataSetX dataSetX));
Collections.addAll(list, getPersons(String a, DataSetY dataSetX));
```

[Read more how to add multiple items to collection in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213974/add-multiple-items-to-an-already-initialized-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: So basically you are saying create 2 lists and merge them in a 3rd. The original function though is more optimal in the sense that it just creates 1 instance of a list. This is what I was trying also to achieve

Comment: @Jim We are writing code for people, not for computer. In addition, [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil). It is better to have simple with good naming code. In addition, you can profile your code with one list and with three lists.

Comment: @Jim Code Good code should be readable, testable. And if it is possible then code should have minimum dependencies and parameters. You will simplify your life and future developers by writing simple code :)

Answer (score 0):

In case if your datasets can be transformed in `Stream` you can try something like this:

```
Stream<Object> streamX = dataSetX.stream().map(e -> processX(e));
Stream<Object> streamY = dataSetY.stream().map(e -> processY(e));
List<Person> persons= Stream.concat(streamX , streamY).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to avoid. The original function loops over 1 list. The approach you mention creates 2 separate lists and then concats then creating a 3rd one. I was trying to keep the advantage of just having 1 instance of a list